# libvirtd and filtered ports

Tags: firewall, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

I am new to `virt-manager`.

After having configured a virtual network (new interface `virbr0`) with 2 VMs that should be able to communicate, I discovered that most ports are filtered.

For example, the two nodes are mutually reachable via port 22, but for other ports, for example higher than 9000, I get a `no route to host`.

trying to connect to the port 80, that is open on host 192.168.122.125, this is what I get with tcpdump:

```
07:50:55.363767 IP 192.168.122.14.54483 > 192.168.122.125.80: Flags [S], seq 21091821, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 313139 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
07:50:55.364204 IP 192.168.122.125 > 192.168.122.14: ICMP host 192.168.122.125 unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
```

Why is this? Is it possible to remove some filters, to allow at least the nodes to be able to communicate on various ports?

Comment: Routing usually doesn't care about ports. Probably the target sends ICMP prohibited packets for the higher ports. Run `tcpdump` while you try to reach those ports and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question adding some tcpdump output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot reach another VM there are two possibilities:

1. The target system blocks the connection with Netfilter (`iptables`).
2. libvirt itself blocks on the virtualized LAN (not meaning VLAN), see http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html

In your case it should be a Netfilter problem. You can be sure about that by running `tcpdump` on the target host, too. you should see the same packets there.

The solution is to adapt the `iptables` configuration but that is not related to Netfilter but to your distro. Thus you should make that a new question if you have problems with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I was able to change the firewall in order to open up ports, and it worked! Now I have a different problem: how to make the changes to the firewall permanent. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175255/how-to-make-firewall-changes-permanent-via-firewall-cmd

Comment: @fstab Then you should consider accepting this answer so that the audience can easily see that this problem is solved.