# how to make firewall changes permanent via firewall-cmd?

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, firewalld, iptables-persistent

I am trying to open some ports in CentOS 7.

I am able to open a port with the following command:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter IN_public_allow 0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 7199 -j ACCEPT
```

By inspecting via `iptables -L -n`, I get the confirmation that the setting was successful:

```
Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7199
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make the changes permanent. Even by using the `--permanent` option like this:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter IN_public_allow 0 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 7199 -j ACCEPT
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Why is the `--permanent` option not working correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`--direct` commands cannot be made permanent. Use equivalent zone command:

```
   sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7199/tcp --permanent
   sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

and to check the result:

```
   sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also do something like this:

`sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7198/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7199/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`

... which will make the current firewall settings perman

Answer (score 2):

there are a lot of ways.. but i am introducing today a method not mentioned here :

```bsh
# firstly run it without --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7199/tcp 
# then run it again with adding --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7199/tcp --permanent
```

it must work